# TFS 2010 Branch Visualisation

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

When I do **Track Changeset** in tfs 2010, then in branch visualisation, I only get to see that selected changeset. However in examples all over the web, I have seen multiple changesets being shown in the hierarchy and Timeline views. Any idea?

What I have got is a main branch and from that I created a dev branch. Then i perform two changsets on dev branch. Now when i do **View History** on dev branch and select any one of the changeset and perform **Track Changeset**, then it only shows me that changeset, which is a bit odd because in the timeline view i should be able to see multiple changesets in a time range. Any idea?

Nabeel

Answer (score 2):

nabeelfarid,

You likely have figured this out by now but this may be of use to others. The activity you are performing is called "Track Changeset" and thus by it's default nature and its name it is tracking a single changeset. It does also seem intuitive to me that in a timeline view I could see changesets that were merge candidates versus a single tracked changeset but that is not how it functions. It is only showing the tracking of a single changeset.

There are instances where instead of seeing a single changeset in the branches the tracked changeset has been merged into that instead you will see multiple changesets show up in one or more branches and usually with an * by them. This happens when the changeset that is being tracked has some of the files in the changeset merged into a target in one merge and checkin operation and some or all of the remaining files of the changeset merged into the target under a second (or more) merge and check-in operation.

Take a quick look at this blog post from John Bowen. He has a nice example that shows a a tracked changeset merged into a parent target branch as multiple changesets made up each of a subset of the files in the tracked changeset. He also shows how that might then look if they were forward integrated from that parent into a different child also by way of multiple changesets. 
[Visualizing Changes Across TFS Branches](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2011/04/06/visualizing-changes-across-tfs-branches/)

Answer (score 1):

If your changesets on dev have not been merged back to your main branch then there is nothing to track. Only as a consequence of merge operation will your dev changes gain a relationship with another changeset (which in your case will be a changeset committed to the main branch).

That is the purpose of the changeset tracking, to help you visualize the propogation of your change across branches. This is useful if you need to verify whether a specific branch has received your changes made on another branch.

(One thing to be aware of is when selecting **Track Changeset**, in the subsequent **Select Branches** dialog select all the branches you want to see in the visualization. It may be the case that just the branch associated with your starting changeset is selected and again you will not see the associated changesets on other branches).

Comment: hi cepdros, well even if the changeset has not been merged back into the main branch, the visualisation should indicate that. Thats the whole point of the visualisation, to view wether the changeset has been merged or not. My question is that I can't see multiple unmerged changeset in the visualisation.